# Dotnet core reactredux template menu mystery

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I generated an app from the new Dotnet core reactredux template using this command: `dotnet new reactredux`

The menu from the generated app is on the left.  I want to change it to the top.  Here's a portion of the NavMenu.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Glyphicon, Nav, Navbar, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import './NavMenu.css';

export default props => (
  <Navbar inverse fixedTop fluid collapseOnSelect>
    <Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <Link to={'/'}>TestCoreReactRedux</Link>
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle />
    </Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Collapse>
```

If I comment out the import of NavMenu.css, the menu now is on top but overlaped the contents. like so
[image]

Is there any way that I can move that down without changing each content page's top margin?

If I changed `<Navbar inverse fixedTop fluid collapseOnSelect>` to `<Navbar default collapseOnSelect>`, I got this
[image]

Note the round rectangle cutting the "Counter" menu.  This rectangle is portional to the width of the window.  F12 reveals that it's the "col-sm-3" class added to a  before the navbar.  Anyone know where that came from and how to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all are in src/components/layout.js.  A simple change like below solved the problems:

```
export default props => (
  <Grid fluid>
    <Row>
      <Col  >
        <NavMenu />
            </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
      <Col >
        {props.children}
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Grid>
);
```